# datatables with jquery multiselect within cells doesn't appear on pag 2 with pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables and have this jquery plugin showing in a few columns http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ it appears in all the cells wehn the page loads, but when I click page 2 or 3 the select button isn't there. The source code for the select menu is in the page but the button for the menu isn't being generated so I don't see it in the cells.

Here's my code for datatables and the select menu

```
var oTable4;
$(document).ready(function() {
            oTable4 = $('#keywords').dataTable( {
        "sDom":'t<"bottom"filp><"clear">',
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [ 
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "10px" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
            ]

    } 
    ).makeEditable({
                        sUpdateURL: "UpdateData.php",
                        "aoColumns": [
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    null,
                                    {                                   
                                    tooltip: 'Click to link to',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    submit:'Ok',
                                    cancel:'Cancel',
                                    width: "100px"}                                 
                                    ]                                   
                });;
                });
$(function(){
    $("select.multiselect").multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: "- select one -",
        header: false,
        classes: "kw-wrapper fixed kwm-button",
        multiple: false,
        selectedList: 1
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you mustr apply the plugin also to the newly created elements. You could use fnDrawCallback() like this:

```
 "fnDrawCallback": function() {
    $("select.multiselect").multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: "- select one -",
        header: false,
        classes: "kw-wrapper fixed kwm-button",
        multiple: false,
        selectedList: 1
    });
  }
```